# Open vent in floor

Tags: vent

In our new house, the pellet stove is downstairs. Above it, is an open vent in the floor for heat to rise to the second floor. Upstairs stays fairly warm because of it. But down the hall to the other end of the upstairs doesn't get the heat from that vent. We've put fans in the hallway, but doesn't really push the heat down into the bedrooms. So i want to install another open vent down at the end of the hall. But i don't know what they are called? I'm trying to google, but only keep coming up with vents/registers attached to ducting. Anyone can help me figure out where to start? Thanks!! Scott

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to understand what you're talking about; would you add a diagram to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: it sounds like you have two registers connected by a very short vertical duct.  there may be a special term for this but I am not aware of it.

Comment: I think it's called "something we don't do anymore because of fire risk" that used to be common in old houses. Duct was not normally part of it, just two holes with grates (often one was closable.)

Answer (score 3):

You did not say what if any other heating system is installed in your house, so I am going to assume that you have a forced air furnace and duct system in your house.

Here is what I did in a house I lived in and heated with a wood stove about 45 years ago. I had a duct company build me a large funnel duct piece to fit on top of the stove.  The top of the funnel piece transitioned to a 7" round duct. I took the 7" round piece and ran it into the cold air return of the furnace. Then I manually turned on the furnace blower to circulate the air to the whole house. The stove heated the air that was collected and I was able to add heat the whole house. The furnace still heated as usual when the stove did not keep up with the needed heating.

If all you want to do is cut a hole in the floor to allow heat from the 1st floor to flow  up to the next floor you could cut a hole in the floor and another hole in the ceiling below and add registers in both holes. I would buy large square floor registers say 10X10 or 12X12 to get adequate air flow. If you want you could have a duct company or an HVAC company make a square duct piece to fit into the square hole you cut to make sure that the air only goes to the room with the registers. If you go this route tell the duct fabricator what you want to do and he can make something that will work.

hope this helps